# Setting system/hardware clock under Debian

Tags: debian, date, time

I have installed a system with a London timezone, instead of using Central European Time. The problem is, that hwclock says the time is 11:00, date says the time is 11:00. I have changed the timezone with tzselect, that also reads the correct value (Prague). And the logs still show that the time is 10:00.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that I had to restart `rsyslogd`.

Comment: theory understanding is that rsyslogd reads hwclock only either once at the start or rereads the hwclock at regular intervals then;  it is better to store timezone value in the logs as well so as to avoid the confusion while read/analyse/decipher log information.